# При парсинге получил не всю инфорамцию. Не могу понять почему

Tags: python, парсер

Новичок. Не судите строго. Скажите, пж, почему не выводится последний span с текстом '61 тыс. км':

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

написал такой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://surgut.drom.ru/lada/all/'
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
# ------------------------------------------
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , 'lxml')
soup
# ------------------------------------------

soup.find('a' , class_ = "css-3jcp5o ewrty961").findAll('span' , class_ = "css-159lyxl e162wx9x0")
```

получил вот это (без (span с текстом '61 тыс. км')):

```
[<span class="css-159lyxl e162wx9x0" data-ftid="bull_description-item">1.8 л (145 л.с.)<!-- -->,</span>,
 <span class="css-159lyxl e162wx9x0" data-ftid="bull_description-item">бензин<!-- -->,</span>,
 <span class="css-159lyxl e162wx9x0" data-ftid="bull_description-item">механика<!-- -->,</span>,
 <span class="css-159lyxl e162wx9x0" data-ftid="bull_description-item">передний</span>]
```

почему? :)

Comment: Скорее всего содержимое сайта генерится на ходу и нужно использовать Selenium

Comment: Скриншот не соответствует полученным данным. На скрине - 87 лошадей, а в полученных данных 145. Может просто не туда посмотрели?